# Unable to install ODBC driver C++ in Apache Ignite

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, odbc, ignite

I am installing  ODBC driver on Centros 6.3, IGNITE_HOME is path/target/release-package , autoconf and automake is installed.

Manually executing this command  libtoolize && aclocal && autoheader && automake --add-missing && autoreconf creates configure file.

This (automake) should generate Makefile.in file.

running ./configure --enable-odbc --disable-node --disable-core

Makefile.in is not generated.

**Error:**

./configure --enable-odbc --disable-node --disable-core 
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu 
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu 
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c 
checking whether build environment is sane... yes 
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p 
checking for gawk... gawk 
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes 
checking for style of include used by make... GNU 
checking for gcc... gcc 
checking whether the C compiler works... yes 
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out 
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no 
checking for suffix of object files... o 
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... rm: cannot remove `core': Is a directory 
yes 
checking whether gcc accepts -g... rm: cannot remove`core': Is a directory 
yes 
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... rm: cannot remove `core': Is a directory 
none needed 
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3 
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E

**autoconf file:**
    root@hostname cpp]# automake 
    configure.ac:39: warning: AC_LANG_CONFTEST: no AC_LANG_SOURCE call detected in body 
    ../../lib/autoconf/lang.m4:193: AC_LANG_CONFTEST is expanded from... 
    ../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2661: _AC_LINK_IFELSE is expanded from... 
    ../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2678: AC_LINK_IFELSE is expanded from... 
    m4/libtool.m4:1022: _LT_SYS_MODULE_PATH_AIX is expanded from... 
    m4/libtool.m4:4161: _LT_LINKER_SHLIBS is expanded from... 
    m4/libtool.m4:5236: _LT_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from... 
    m4/libtool.m4:138: _LT_SETUP is expanded from... 
    m4/libtool.m4:67: LT_INIT is expanded from... 
    configure.ac:39: the top level 
    configure.ac:39: warning: AC_LANG_CONFTEST: no AC_LANG_SOURCE call detected in body 
    ../../lib/autoconf/lang.m4:193: AC_LANG_CONFTEST is expanded from... 
    ../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2661: _AC_LINK_IFELSE is expanded from... 
    ../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2678: AC_LINK_IFELSE is expanded from... 
    m4/libtool.m4:4161: _LT_LINKER_SHLIBS is expanded from... 
    m4/libtool.m4:5236: _LT_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from... 
    m4/libtool.m4:138: _LT_SETUP is expanded from... 
    m4/libtool.m4:67: LT_INIT is expanded from... 
    configure.ac:39: the top level 
    /usr/share/automake-1.11/am/depend2.am: am__fastdepCXX does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL 
    /usr/share/automake-1.11/am/depend2.am:   The usual way to define `am__fastdepCXX' is to add`AC_PROG_CXX' 
    /usr/share/automake-1.11/am/depend2.am:   to `configure.ac' and run`aclocal' and `autoconf' again. 
    binary/Makefile.am: C++ source seen but`CXX' is undefined 
    binary/Makefile.am:   The usual way to define `CXX' is to add`AC_PROG_CXX' 
    binary/Makefile.am:   to `configure.ac' and run`autoconf' again. 
    common/Makefile.am: C++ source seen but `CXX' is undefined 
    common/Makefile.am:   The usual way to define`CXX' is to add `AC_PROG_CXX' 
    common/Makefile.am:   to`configure.ac' and run `autoconf' again. 
    core/Makefile.am: C++ source seen but`CXX' is undefined 
    core/Makefile.am:   The usual way to define `CXX' is to add`AC_PROG_CXX' 
    core/Makefile.am:   to `configure.ac' and run`autoconf' again. 
    ignite/Makefile.am: C++ source seen but `CXX' is undefined 
    ignite/Makefile.am:   The usual way to define`CXX' is to add `AC_PROG_CXX' 
    ignite/Makefile.am:   to`configure.ac' and run `autoconf' again. 
    jni/Makefile.am: C++ source seen but`CXX' is undefined 
    jni/Makefile.am:   The usual way to define `CXX' is to add`AC_PROG_CXX' 
    jni/Makefile.am:   to `configure.ac' and run`autoconf' again. 
    odbc/Makefile.am: C++ source seen but `CXX' is undefined 
    odbc/Makefile.am:   The usual way to define`CXX' is to add `AC_PROG_CXX' 
    odbc/Makefile.am:   to`configure.ac' and run `autoconf' again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Makefile.in should be created by automake. Please make sure you have C++ compiler on your system. You need that to compile ODBC driver.

Try changing AC_PROG_CPP to AC_PROG_CXX in configure.ac file.

Comment: Yes,  gcc compiler is present on my system. Modifying that did worked.